# neo4j: How to use both start and match clause

Tags: neo4j

i am new to neo4j.

First, i enable node auto index and relationship auto index in neo4j.properties, and add property key person_name,hotel_name for node. property key inTime for relationship.
Then i created data as below:

```
create (:Person {person_name:'p1'})
create (:Person {person_name:'p2'})
create (:Hotel {hotel_name:'h1'} )
create (:Hotel {hotel_name:'h2'} )

start p=node:node_auto_index('person_name:p1'),h=node:node_auto_index('hotel_name:h1')
create (p)-[:STAY_IN {inTime:'20140520'}]->(h)

start p=node:node_auto_index('person_name:p1'),h=node:node_auto_index('hotel_name:h2')
create (p)-[:STAY_IN {inTime:'20140522'}]->(h)

start p=node:node_auto_index('person_name:p2'),h=node:node_auto_index('hotel_name:h1')
create (p)-[:STAY_IN {inTime:'20140510'}]->(h)
```

Now, i want to query the result that person p1 STAY_IN h1 between 20140501 and 20140530:

but the cypher return data all:

```
start p=node:node_auto_index('person_name:p1'),
      r=relationship:relationship_auto_index('inTime:[20140501 TO 20140530]')  
      match (p)-[r]-(h) return p,r,h
```

It returned both p1 and p2, i only want the p1 return.

Can anybody help me? Thank you very much.

Because there are hurge data in my real neo4j db. a lot of nodes and relationships. So i have to use both node and relationship index for performance.

Comment: Works for me: http://console.neo4j.org/r/olczb3

Comment: But I would probably use: `start 
      r=relationship:relationship_auto_index('inTime:[20140501 TO 20140530]')  
      match (p)-[r]-(h) where p.person_name = 'p1' return p,r,h`

Comment: Because there are hurge data in my real neo4j db. a lot of nodes and relationships. So i have to use both node and relationship index.
This Cypher you demonstrated, Does it will use node auto-index?
I have seen that if i want to use the auto-index it must be put in start clause in the neo manual. Am i wrong?

Comment: Hi, @Michael Hunger, Are you still here?